# How to save dragonfly attachment directly to s3 without hitting the rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, redis, dragonfly-gem

I have setup-ed my rails application to use `dragonfly + s3`. Everything works fine up till here. and i have deployed my rails application on `Heroku`. `Now i want to upload my images to s3 without hitting the rails server, as due to heavy uploading my rails server crashes`. I want some way to insert `Redis` into picture so that images are queued to Redis and `sidekiq or Resque` will process them in background.My question is what should be the approach to do such thing. Is there any ruby library exists to achieve this.Any help is appreciated.